# How effective are digital blue-light filters for secretion of melatonin & getting to sleep?

Tags: sleep, circadian-rythym, light

Programs like f.lux (Desktop Application) and features like Night Mode (iOS) claim to reduce the blue light being emitted from a digital screen to improve sleep. Is this true, and if so, how effective is it?